# Springboot stream

Tags: spring-boot, streaming

I have a springboot API which is dealing with lot of processes in backend. I need to stream the status to the frontend. Since I am new to springboot can anyone help me how to achieve this scenario.

Note - Application is going to be containerized in future and I cannot use any cloud service for this.

Comment: What do you mean with stream the status to the frontend? Would [Server Sent Events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events) satisfy your needs?

Comment: I have a backend process which process the large files and meanwhile I need to send the logs to UI so that status can be shown for the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is not much to go off of I will try my best:
If you are using Log4j2 you could simply use[the SocketAppender (external link)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender)

If not:
I did something similar recently and you will need to somehow turn your logs into a stream. I'd advise using the information found [here (non-external link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058722/creating-an-outputstreamappender-for-logback)

```
OutputStream Stream;

@GetMapping("/stream-sse-mvc")
public SseEmitter streamSseMvc() {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    ExecutorService sseMvcExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    sseMvcExecutor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            Stream.map(sequence -> SseEmitter.event()
                   .id(""))
                   .event("EVENT_TYPE")
                   .data("String.valueOf(sequence)
                   .build());
                emitter.send(event);
                Thread.sleep(1000); //This does not need to be here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            emitter.completeWithError(ex);
        }
    });
    return emitter;
}
```

There might be better ways to reach your endpoints but without knowing what Frameworks you are using this is hard to answer. Essentially what we are doing is capturing all log output to a stream which is then broadcasted by an SSE.

Comment: Thanks @SirHawrk  !! This really helped to resolve my purpose. 
In given solution we are using MVC SSE. In spring 5 we can use SSE with webflux. But not sure which is the best way ?